# Как получить сколько человек подписано на определенный пост через m2m? Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, many-to-many

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)

class Profile((models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    follows = models.ManyToManyField(Post, blank=True)
```

Вопрос в том как получить количество подписок на определенный пост? В follows хранятся профили соединенные с моделью постами. Как получить сколько человек подписано  на определенный пост? Если можно, реализовать простым способом или объяснить (я новичок)

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: Я потратил 5 часов и понял, что я не правильно прочитал документацию. Я получал профиль модели, а профиль только потом связан с user (OneToOneField). Спасибо!!!